# Remote tar file and transfer from solaris to windoe

Tags: unix

The server running Win2k3 sp2 ,with psftp to remote get the file from Solaris 9 to Window folder.  There are 450G file in Solaris  need to  tar or ufsdump to transfer the tar file or dump to Window without keep it on Solaris server.   Can you advice how to do that or alternative method.

Comment: What problems do you have with psftp (putty)? Seems to be secure and fast enough

Comment: i have no idea command for psftp to tar and put it on window

Comment: it works in similar way to sftp, check here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95993/how-to-make-tar-save-the-archive-on-a-remote-machine-using-sftp-or-ftp

Comment: Thank you @AntonMalyshev